# Как сделать правильно выборку в шаблон laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel, blade

Всем привет. Есть шаблон app.blade.php, в него входит шапка, и в шапке должно быть имя пользователя(из бд). Как сделать так что бы прямо в шаблон передавать один раз, и на все страницах работало? Как именно передать это в шаблон? У него нет контролера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ — создать Middleware `ShareCurrentUser`:

```
public function handle($request, $next) 
{
    if ($user = \Auth::user() && !$request->wantsJson()) {
        \View::share('currentUser', $user);  
    }
    return $next;
}
```

Не забудьте добавить его в группу web в Kernel.php.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.